# (windows 10) WinRE has no other options other than "Turn off your PC"

Tags: windows-10, uefi

[pic of winRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irhHF.jpg)

hello recently I have removed arch Linux from machine, and wanted to re-install it... after removing it something happened with my Windows's winRE options... all of the options disappeared except "Turn off your PC".

does anyone know why does this happens and have any solution?

my goal is to bring all those option back again :)

thanks much

Comment: I think (even in the screen you show) that is a Windows function (part of the startup function).  Look through this tutorial here to see if you can add back the power button items.   https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7456-add-remove-sleep-power-menu-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @John what does this problem has to do with sleep? i don't understand... thanks :)

Comment: If it is a BIOS function (I have not changed BIOS in this way) try this Microsoft article for BIOS power buttons.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode

Comment: Hey, that is not your UEFI firmware, it is the WinRE environment.

Comment: oh, my bad thanks for the corrections @Wasif_Hasan